# (Python TKinter) Mainloop resets my variables

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have recently started learning python and now wanted to code something with a gui. So I watched a few tutorials to tkinter and it all seemed to be working fine, until I noticed, that variables I declared at the start of the program (in this case lists) were being reset after every button press.

I wanted to create objects that I save in a list and at the end of the program return values from these objects.
The problem is likely that mainloop keeps repeating the entire code, including `room_list = []`, which I put at the beginning.

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk
    
room_list = []
comp_list = []

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Maklerhelper')

lbl_title = tk.Label()
frm_entries = tk.Frame()
ent_input_one = tk.Entry(master = frm_entries)
ent_input_two = tk.Entry(master = frm_entries)
frm_buttons = tk.Frame()
btn_one = tk.Button(master = frm_buttons)
btn_two = tk.Button(master = frm_buttons)
lbl_error = tk.Label()

lbl_title.pack(pady = 20)
frm_entries.pack()
ent_input_one.pack(side = tk.LEFT, padx = 5)
ent_input_two.pack(side = tk.LEFT, padx = 5)
frm_buttons.pack(pady = 20)
lbl_error.pack()
btn_one.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
btn_two.pack(side = tk.RIGHT)

class room:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.comps = []
        self.area = 0
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Raum: {self.name}, Fläche: {self.area}'
        
    def addroom(self):
        self.comps = comp_list
        
    def calc_area(self):
        for compartment in self.comps:
            self.area += compartment[0] * compartment[1]

def reset_layout():
    lbl_title.pack_forget()
    frm_entries.pack_forget()
    ent_input_one.pack_forget()
    ent_input_two.pack_forget()
    frm_buttons.pack_forget()
    lbl_error.pack_forget()
    btn_one.pack_forget()
    btn_two.pack_forget()
    
    ent_input_one.delete(0, tk.END)
    ent_input_two.delete(0, tk.END)
    
    lbl_title.pack(pady = 20)
    frm_entries.pack()
    ent_input_one.pack(side = tk.LEFT, padx = 5)
    ent_input_two.pack(side = tk.LEFT, padx = 5)
    frm_buttons.pack(pady = 20)
    lbl_error.pack()
    btn_one.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
    btn_two.pack(side = tk.RIGHT)

def calculate():
    room_list = quicksort(room_list)
    outp = room_list[0]
    
    for x in range(1, len(room_list)-1):
        outp += f'\n {room_list[x]}'
        
    area_sum = 0
    
    for x in room_list:
        area_sum += x.area
    
    avg_area = area_sum / len(room_list)
    outp += f'\n Gesamtfläche: {area_sum}\n Durchschnittliche Raumgröße: {avg_area}'
    reset_layout()
    
    frm_entries.pack_forget()
    ent_input_one.pack_forget()
    ent_input_two.pack_forget()
    frm_buttons.pack_forget()
    lbl_error.pack_forget()
    btn_one.pack_forget()
    btn_two.pack_forget()
    
    lbl_title.config(
        text = outp,
        font = 'Verdana 10')
    

def quicksort(f_list):
    if len(f_list) <= 1:
        return f_list
    pivot = f_list[-1].area
    left_index = 0
    right_index = len(f_list)-1
    while right_index > left_index+1:
        while f_list[right_index].area >= pivot and right_index > left_index+1:
            right_index -= 1
        while f_list[left_index].area < pivot and right_index > left_index+1:
            left_index += 1
        if f_list[left_index].area >= pivot:
            f_list[left_index], f_list[right_index] = f_list[right_index], f_list[left_index]
    if f_list[right_index].area < pivot:
        right_index += 1
        left_index += 1
    f_list[right_index], f_list[-1] = f_list[-1], f_list[right_index]
    f_list[:right_index] = quicksort(f_list[:right_index])
    f_list[right_index:] = quicksort(f_list[right_index:])                
    return f_list

def rectangular():
    reset_layout()
    
    lbl_title.config(text = 'Gib die Raumlängen in Metern an!')
    ent_input_one.config(width = 10)
    ent_input_two.config(width = 10)
    btn_one.config(
        text = 'Bestätigen',
        command = rect_done)
    btn_two.pack_forget()
    lbl_error.pack_forget()

def polygon():
    reset_layout()
    
    lbl_title.config(text = 'Bitte die Längen eines rechteckigen Abteils in Metern angeben!')
    ent_input_one.config(width = 10)
    ent_input_two.config(width = 10)
    btn_one.config(
        text = 'Bestätigen',
        command = more_comps)
    btn_two.pack_forget()
    lbl_error.pack_forget()
        
def room_done(): 
    room_list[-1].addroom()
    room_list[-1].calc_area()
    comp_list.clear()
    reset_layout()
    
    lbl_title.config(text = 'Gibt es einen weiteren Raum?')
    frm_entries.pack_forget()
    btn_one.config(
        text = 'ja',
        command = new_room)
    btn_two.config(
        text = 'nein',
        command = calculate)
    lbl_error.pack_forget()
    
def rect_done():
    if ent_input_one.get() and ent_input_two.get():
        length_one = ent_input_one.get()
        length_two = ent_input_two.get()
        try:
            length_one = float(length_one)
            length_two = float(length_two)
            comp_list = [length_one, length_two]
            room_done()
        except:
            lbl_error.config(text = 'Bitte als Zahl im Format ##.# angeben!')
            lbl_error.pack()
    
def more_comps():
    if ent_input_one.get() and ent_input_two.get():
        length_one = ''
        length_two = ''
        try:
            length_one = float(ent_input_one.get())
            length_two = float(ent_input_two.get())
        except:
            length_one = ''
        if isinstance(length_one, float) and isinstance(length_two, float):
            comp_list.append([length_one, length_two])
            
            reset_layout()
            
            lbl_title.config(text = 'Gibt es ein weiteres Abteil?')
            frm_entries.pack_forget()
            btn_one.config(
                text = 'ja',
                command = polygon)
            btn_two.config(
                text = 'nein',
                command = room_done)
            lbl_error.pack_forget()
            
        else:
            lbl_error.pack()
            lbl_error.config(text = 'Bitte als Zahl im Format ##.# angeben!')
    else:
        lbl_error.pack()
        lbl_error.config(text = 'Bitte in beiden Feldern Längen angeben!')

def new_room():
    reset_layout()
    
    lbl_title.config(text = 'Gib die Bezeichnung des Raums ein!')
    ent_input_one.config(width = 50)
    ent_input_two.pack_forget()
    btn_one.config(
        text = 'Bestätigen',
        command = rect_or_poly)
    btn_two.pack_forget()
    lbl_error.pack_forget()
    
def rect_or_poly():
    if ent_input_one.get():
        room_list.append(room(ent_input_one.get()))
        
        reset_layout()
        
        lbl_title.config(text = 'Ist der Raum rechteckig?')
        frm_entries.pack_forget()
        btn_one.config(text = 'ja', command = rectangular)
        btn_two.config(text = 'nein', command = polygon)
        lbl_error.pack_forget()
    else:
        lbl_error.pack()
        lbl_error.config(text = 'Bitte Raumbezeichnung angeben!')

new_room()

window.mainloop()
```

Is there some way to exclude the initialization of the variables from the mainloop somehow?
I was thinking about checking if they are empty in an if statement, but that doesn't make sense in my head

Debugging with prints:
added prints into `room_done()` and `rect_done()` then accessed `room_done()` through `rect_done()` using the inputs 4 for `ent_input_one` and 5 for `ent_input_two`

```
def room_done(): 
    print(comp_list)
    #room_list[-1].addroom()
    #room_list[-1].calc_area()
    #comp_list.clear()
    reset_layout()
    
    lbl_title.config(text = 'Gibt es einen weiteren Raum?')
    frm_entries.pack_forget()
    btn_one.config(
        text = 'ja',
        command = new_room)
    btn_two.config(
        text = 'nein',
        command = calculate)
    lbl_error.pack_forget()
    
def rect_done():
    if ent_input_one.get() and ent_input_two.get():
        length_one = ent_input_one.get()
        length_two = ent_input_two.get()
        try:
            length_one = float(length_one)
            length_two = float(length_two)
            comp_list = [length_one, length_two]
            print(comp_list)
            room_done()
        except:
            lbl_error.config(text = 'Bitte als Zahl im Format ##.# angeben!')
            lbl_error.pack()
```

output was:

```
[4.0, 5.0]
[]
```

Comment: If the variables are being reset after a button press, then the code that declares the button and handles the click is relevant to the question and should be included.

Comment: I left it out initially, because I am certain, that it resets, because the `comp_list = []` gets executed with each loop of the mainloop(), which empties the list. I added it in now though

Comment: well, `comp_list` is cleared inside the function `room_done()`  (third line in this function does `comp_list.clear()` ). Are you sure it's not here where it gets emptied? Verifying is as easy as running the program in debug mode and putting breakpoints, so you every time that a line is executed. Debugging the code also allows you to see the value of the list and execute the lines one by one, so you can see exactly when it gets cleared

Comment: I verified that with printing the `comp_list` already. I want to use the `comp_list` in the `room_list[-1].addroom()` method, so I put print statements in the `addroom()` method. Each time I arrived there, `comp_list` was empty, even though I only clear it two lines after that.    I enter `room_done()` through `more_comps()` btn_two press and through `rect_done()`. I put print statements in both of those, and in both cases `comp_list` still had contents, but once the `room_done()` method started, it was empty again, which is why I came to the conclusion that it must be due to the mainloop

Comment: Use a debugger, execute line by line and check at what point it gets cleared.

Comment: I tried that at first, but the debugger didn't work with the gui, so I checked it with the many `print(comp_list)` instead. I am not sure why it doesn't work, but it goes through `new_room()` once, then stops at mainloop() and opens the gui and after that it just does nothing anymore

Comment: showed the print debugging and the result in an edit

Comment: it looks you are modifying the global variable comp_list without using the keyboard global.  try adding `global comp_list` at the beginning of any function that modifies the global list

Comment: re: _"The problem is likely that mainloop keeps repeating the entire code"_ - mainloop doesn't repeat any code. It's just a loop that listens for events and calls callbacks.

Comment: The problem was the global. It got solved when I changed the `comp_list = [length_one, length_two]` to `comp_list.append([length_one, length_two]` For the room_list I had to put `global room_list` into my `calculate()` method

Comment: If you solved the problem, please answer your own question. Also edit the question for the [mre] guide.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the global. It got solved when I changed the `comp_list = [length_one, length_two]` to `comp_list.append([length_one, length_two]` For the room_list I had to put `global room_list` into my `calculate()` method